# How to zcat a zip file saved from pandas.to_csv

Tags: pandas, bash, macos, zip, unzip

I've been using pandas.to_csv on a mac to save csv.zip files. When I try to zless or zcat them on my mac, I see gibberish. I can read_csv them just fine. `locale` gives me

```
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

If that helps. Does anyone know what I need to do to be able to open them from the command line?

Comment: initial thoughts: 1. in bash, what does `file <filename>` show? 2. if not already, try setting `compression='zip'` explicitly in `to_csv()`

Comment: `zcat` is for gzipped files, not zip archives...

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have to `unzip` the file. You can use `unzip -c` to print to stdout and pipe to something else. You'll some meta data at the beginning you can trim with `tail`.